# Is "garbage value" random? I'm pretty sure my garbage value was just 1 is it possible?? :o

Tags: c, random, garbage

Okay so I have this program of mine:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int deCode(int x[2][5])
{
    return x[2][4]; // Heres where the "garbage" comes in.
}    //     calling x[2][4] is non valued function. I can call [0,1][0,1,2,3,4]

int main(void)
{
    int newPosition;
    int x[2][5]={
                {1,3,5,7,9}, //[0][0-4] // row 0
                {2,4,6,8,10} //[1][0-4] // row 1
                };                      //NOTICE NO ROW 2
    printf("%d\n", deCode(&x));
}
```

I got value 1 when I play this program. Obviously you probably wont get the same resolut.
when i do [2][1,2,3,5] I get true garbage. Im just wondering is that like
one in a million chance or am I missing something?

Comment: shoud be `printf("%d\n", deCode(x));`

Answer (score 4):

It's definitely *not* random. It's undefined.

For instance, you may just be reading *another* variable. If that variable were the the character array `\0\0\0\0\0...` you would be reading a lot of zeros. If it were the `int` array `1, 1, 1, 1...` you would read 1's.

Very often you'll see numbers like `2^32-1`, which you may be quick to recognize. Things like that happen when you accidentally interpret a signed int as an unsigned int.

One strategy in debugging is to initialize all memory to [0xCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747852/int-3-0xcc-x86-asm). Then you will not receive raw memory, you will see 0xCC, which has a very good chance of crashing your program instead of being silently accepted.

Comment: Indeterminate is a good word — the values are indeterminate but not random in the sense of a good PRNG.  Not that undefined is wrong; the values are not defined by the standard.  And the code invokes undefined behaviour by accessing memory outside the bounds of the array it is passed.